# Export actions from Blender action editor to ThreeJS

Tags: three.js, blender

On linux, i'm using:

- the last vestion of Blender (2.79b)
- the last version of ThreeJS (r95).

With Blender, i created a very simple rigged mesh and created several actions with the "Action Editor".

I would like to export to ThreeJS and be able to animate my character by calling the actions by their name.

I haven't found a clear tutorial on this subject on the internet regarding the latest versions of ThreeJS.

More over, i installed the Blender exporter, but when i want to load the json file,i get an error "three.min.js:737 THREE.JSONLoader: /public/scene/dae/r91/robot.json should be loaded with THREE.ObjectLoader instead."

Does anyone have a good tutorial to suggest for my case? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The three.js JSON exporter has several bugs (like [three.js#6326](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/6326)) related to exporting multiple animations.

As an alternative, you can use Blender to export to glTF, then load with `THREE.GLTFLoader`.

- https://github.com/Kupoman/blendergltf
- KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter (experimental support for multiple animations [here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter/pull/166))

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried with a very simple mesh (cubes) and it works, i can play the different actions. Unfortunately, with i try with my normal mesh, it is totally deformed. On ThreeJS, deformation occurs as soon as i apply the "With automatic weights" to the armature.

Comment: Which exporter? May want to file an issue on that exporter if you can reproduce the deformation on [multiple](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/) glTF [viewers](http://sandbox.babylonjs.com/).

Comment: Kupoman exporter works (but had to attached bones with vertex groups, instead automatic weights). By con, KhronosGroup exporter doesn't work (see only 1 action).